# Need to return multiple entries from a single field in One Table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So Here is the problem I have a requirement where I need a customer type to equal two different things.

To Cover the requirement I don't need the customer type to equal Client, or Non client but equal Client, and Non_Client. Each Customer_No  can have multiple Customer Types

Here is an example of what I have worked on so far. If you know a better way of optimizing this as well as solving the problem please let me know.

The out put should look like this

```
 CustomerID  CustomerType  CustomerType 
 --------------------------------------
 2345        Client        NonClient


Select TB1.Customer_ID, IB1.Customer_Type, AS Non_client IB1.Customer_Type AS Client
From Client TB1, Client_ReF XB1, Client_Instr IB1, Client_XREC FB1
Where XB1.Client_NO = TB1.Client_NO
AND FB1.Client_ACCT = TB1.ACCT
AND XB1.Client_Instruct_NO = IB1.Client_Instruct_NO
AND FB1.Customer_ID= TB1. Client_NO
AND IB1.Client = 'Client' 
AND IB1.Non_Client = 'NonClient'
```

I have omitted a few other filters that I felt were unnecessary. This also may not make sense, but I tried to change up the names of stuff as to keep myself in compliance.

Comment: How `IB1.Customer_Type, AS Non_client IB1.Customer_Type AS Client` can work? And this: `AND FB1.Customer_ID= TB1. Client_NO
Where Customer Type = 'Client'`

Comment: Why are you selecting the same column `IB1.Customer_Type` twice? Wouldn't it make more sense to select it once and use it twice wherever its going?

Comment: It was my first attempt. Still learning SQL

Comment: you cant have double `where`. I guess second one is a `and`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a small syntactic error:

You mustn't have a comma before the "AS Non_client "

Then what you are trying to do is make 1 value equal 2 different things for the same column which can never be true:

IB1.Customer_Type for 1 record can never be equal to "Client" and "NonClient" simultaneously.

The key here is that 1 customer can have multiple records and the records can differ in the customer_type. So to use that we need to join those records together which is easy since they share a Customer_ID:

```
Select TB1.Customer_ID, 
       IB1.Customer_Type AS Client, 
       IB2.Customer_Type AS Non_client
  From Client TB1, 
       Client_ReF XB1, 
       Client_Instr IB1, 
       Client_Instr IB2,
       Client_XREC FB1 
 Where XB1.Client_NO = TB1.Client_NO
   AND FB1.Client_ACCT = TB1.ACCT 
   AND XB1.Client_Instruct_NO = IB1.Client_Instruct_NO 
   AND FB1.Customer_ID= TB1.Client_NO 
   AND IB1.Client = 'Client'  
   AND XB1.Client_Instruct_NO = IB2.Client_Instruct_NO 
   AND IB2.Non_Client = 'NonClient';
```

The above may not actually work due to me not fully understanding your data and structures but should put you on the right path. Particularly around the join of IB2 with XB1, you might have to join IB2 with all the same tables as IB1.

A better way than that however, and i'll leave you to research it, is using the EXISTS statement. The difference is that the above will join all records for the same customer together whereas EXISTS will just be satisfied if there's at least 1 instance of a "NonClient" record.